# As a bard, can the feat prodigy give me expertise on a skill that my bard expertise is on?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, skills, bard

I am currently playing a half orc bard and have been considering what feat to choose once I hit level 4. I currently have expertise on my perception and I saw I can take the prodigy feat, where I can gain proficiency on a skill and expertise. However I noticed it never mentioned how it needs to be a skill that doesn’t have expertise already. Can I put the expertise on my perception again so it’s double expertise?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.